# How to submit html tags in php form?

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

The form is

```
    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >

       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">URL </label>
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uurl" placeholder="url" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sql['url']); ?>">                          
          </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
              <button type="submit" name="posted" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button> 
          </div>
       </div>
</form>
```

---

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iZqDfqsOiRM
?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This iframe code i want to send to mysql db through the form.
P.s The form works fine if i don't use this iframe code as input. But i need to submit the form with these tags

The form submit code is below

```
if(isset($_POST['posted'])){
  extract($_POST);
  $eid=$_GET['eid']; 
   if($mysqli_query($con, " UPDATE channel SET title = '$utitle', url = '$uurl', picture = '$upicture', datetime = '$udatetime', status = '$ustatus', type='$utype' WHERE id = '$eid' ")){
    echo '<script> alert("Record Updated"); </script>';
   } 
}
```

Comment: Please add the PHP code that you're using to submit the data.

Comment: maybe there's a mismatch with your db type

Comment: @rpm192 edited. Please check

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you checked what the error message means?

Comment: I know this is not your question, but warning bells should ring every time you use non sanitized variables in a database query string. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Why exactly do you need to submit the  _entire_ iframe? Can't you just insert the actual url and echo it in the `src=` attribute?